# Number of steady states in systems of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Currently I'm studying (qualitatively) the behaviour of systems of nonlinear, autonomous ODEs, e.g.:

$$ \begin{array}{lcl} \dot{x_1} & = & x_1-x_1^2-x_1x_2 \\
\dot{x_2} & = & 3x_2-x_1x_2-x_2^2 \end{array} $$

Generally I'm well aware how this is done (Find the steady states, linearize, investigate the Jacobian of each steady state etc.), however sometimes I "miss" one or two steady-states since they are not always easy to find/see. Therefore: Is there a way to know (a priori) how many steady states a system of nonlinear, autonomous ODEs has?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. The steady state solutions for problems of this type solve a system polynomial equations. It is known that a system of $n$ polynomial equations of degrees $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$ has at most $d_1d_2 \dots d_n$ solutions. This bound is sharp (a result known as Bezout's Theorem) and grows exponentially in $n$. So the answer to your question is "no, probably not".